# Sending a 2D int array between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, cuda

I'm trying to create a solution where I can run a 2D int array within a C# program through CUDA, so the approach I'm currently taking to try and do this is by creating a C++ dll which can handle the CUDA code then return the 2D array. The code I'm using to send my array to the dll and back again is below.

```
#include "CudaDLL.h"
#include <stdexcept>

int** cudaArrayData;

void CudaDLL::InitialiseArray(int arrayRows, int arrayCols, int** arrayData)
{
    cudaArrayData = new int*[arrayCols];
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayCols; i++)
    {
        cudaArrayData[i] = new int[arrayRows];
    }

    cudaArrayData = arrayData;
}

int** CudaDLL::ReturnArray()
{
    return cudaArrayData;
}
```

The problem however is I get an error in C# on the return, "Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination." My hope was if I returned the array back as a pointer C# might have hopefully understood and accepted it however no such luck.

Any idea's?

Comment: How does your C# code look like? Are you using int[][] or int[,]?

Comment: int[,] should I use int[][] I tbh didn't know there was a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you’re using `int[,]` in C#, `int**` is not the right corresponding type in C++. `int[][]` is an array of arrays of ints, similar to `int**` in C++; whereas `int[,]` is one array of ints with 2D indexing: `index = x + y * width`. Using `int**` in C#/C++ interop is difficult, as you have many pointers to either managed or unmanaged memory, which is not directly accessible from one to another (see further down).

Already in `InitialiseArray(..., int** arrayData)` you read somewhere in your memory but not in array values as you don't pass an array with pointers to arrays of ints, you pass one single array of int.

When you return `int**` in ReturnArray(), your problem is that .net has no clue how to interpret that pointer to an pointer.

To fix this, use only `int*` on C++ side and don’t return the array as a function return value, this would only give you a pointer to the unmanaged array and not the entire data in managed memory. It is possible to use this from C#, but probably not in the way you intend to do. Use an array allocated in C# as function argument in `void ReturnArray(int* retValues)` to copy the data to.

The other problem is then data copying and memory allocations. You can avoid all of these steps if you handle memory in C# right, i.e. forbid the garbage collector to move your data around (it does that when cleaning up unused objects). Either use a fixed{} statement or do it manually via GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned). Doing so, you can directly use the C# allocated arrays from within C++.

Finally, if all you need is to let a CUDA kernel run on your C# data, have a look at some cuda wrappers that handle all the Pinvoke hazards for you. Like [managedCuda](http://managedcuda.codeplex.com/) (I maintain this project) or [cudafy](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/) and some others.

Comment: Excellent thank you for that, I'll look into this further then as it's uncharted territory for me at the moment haha.